# prefix every header column with string using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a bunch of big csv I want to prefix every header column with fixed string. There is more than 500 columns in every file.

suppose my header is:

```
number;date;customer;key;amount
```

I tried this awk line:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1{gsub(/[^a-z_]/,"input_file.")} { print }'
```

but I get (note fist column is missing prefix and separator is removed):

```
numberinput_file.dateinput_file.customerinput_file.keyinput_file.amount
```

expected output:

```
input_file.number;input_file.date;input_file.customer;input_file.key;input_file.amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gsub` would brutally replace any nonalphabetic character anywhere in the input with the prefix - including your column separators.

The `print` can be abbreviated to the common idiom `1` at the very end of your script; this simply means "this condition is true; perform the default action for every line (i.e. print it all)" though this is just a stylistic change.

```sh
awk -F';' 'NR==1{
    sub(/^/, "input_file."); gsub(/;/, ";input_file."); }
  1' filename
```

If you want to perform this on multiple files, probably put a shell loop around it. If you only want to concatenate everything to standard output, you can give all the files to Awk in one go (in which case you probably don't want to print the header line for any file after the first; maybe change the `1` to `NR==1 || FNR != 1`).

Comment: no, in this case setting FS/OFS doesn't make any difference... this is equivalent to `sed '1 s/[^;]*/input_file.&/g'`

Answer (score 2):

In any awk that'd be:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{gsub(/^|;/,"&input_file.")} 1' file
input_file.number;input_file.date;input_file.customer;input_file.key;input_file.amount
```

but sed exists to do simple substitutions like that, e.g. using a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs (e.g. GNU and BSD sed):

```
$ sed -E '1s/^|;/&input_file./g' file
input_file.number;input_file.date;input_file.customer;input_file.key;input_file.amount
```

If you're using GNU tools then you could use either of the above to change all of your CSV files at once with either of these:

```
awk -i inplace 'NR==1{gsub(/^|;/,"&input_file.")} 1' *.csv
sed -i -E '1s/^|;/&input_file./g' *.csv
```

Comment: tested both. awk seems way much faster. Thanks

Comment: That is hard to believe as awk does more work per input line than sed does. Are you sure you did 3rd-run timing for each and you're not just seeing a cache-ing impact?

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
number;date;customer;key;amount
1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=";input_file."}NR==1{$1="input_file." $1}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
input_file.number;input_file.date;input_file.customer;input_file.key;input_file.amount
1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10
```

Explanation: I set `OFS` to `;` followed by prefix. Then in first line I add prefix to first column, which trigger string rebuilding. No modification is done in any other line, thus they are `print`ed as is.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk` using `for` loop and `printf`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", "input_file." $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' file
input_file.number;input_file.date;input_file.customer;input_file.key;input_file.amount
```